# Django Pillow saving thumbnail image

Tags: python, django, image, python-imaging-library

When trying to save only the thumbnail version of the form posted image I get the following error.
`'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'write'`

Using either of the following will produce the same error. I think that what I'm missing here is some kind write mode definition. The Image.open only accepts `'r'` mode though.

Model save method

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    img = Image.open(self.image)
    img.thumbnail((250, 250), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save(img, 'JPEG')   
    super(EventPost, self).save()
```

Formviews form_valid method

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    img = Image.open(form.cleaned_data['image'])
    img.thumbnail((250, 250), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save(img, 'JPEG')
    form.save(commit=True)
    return super(FormPage, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: this [tutorial](https://python.web.id/blog/how-to-make-thumbnail-in-django-with-pillow/) will help you

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is:

```
img = img.thumbnail((250,250), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

And then save if you want to save only the thumbnail. And the save() method of the image accepts path as first argument not file:

```
img.save("path/to/save/image", "JPEG", quality=from1to100, optimize=bool, progressive=bool)
```

Comment: `img = img.thumbnail((250,250), Image.ANTIALIAS)` loses the image object and tries to save a `None` type object. Without it, using the path I get `[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'media/media/images'` when saving. This is atleast when working on localhost.

Comment: Does your media folder have full permissions? try sudo chmod -R 777 my/folder

Comment: Doesn't help. Tried on the actual site also and even there produces the same error...  There must be something that I'm missing here